# Prove $v(t)$ is a Markov Process, find its' transition density and its' generator.

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

If $v(t)$ is the velocity of the spherical particle is $v(t) = v(0)e^{-\alpha t} + \frac{\sigma}{m} \int_0^t{e^{-\alpha(t-s)}}dw(s)$ with mass $m$, radius $r$, $\alpha = \frac{\sigma \pi r \eta}{m}$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{2m\alpha KT}$. $w(s)$ is the Wiener process. The process $V(t)$ is supposed to be the Ornstein-Ulenbek process. But, I don't see how? The definition does not match the definition of the process in Wikipedia. And I am not sure how to go about proving that it is a Markov Process.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your formula. The upper bound of integration in the stochastic integral has to be $t$ not $1$. Then, differantiating in $t$ you can easily check that you $v_{t}$ satisfies the OU-SDE. Apart, you do also find that formula on wikipedia.

Comment: I fixed it but, I am still not sure how to prove that it's a Markov process apart from saying that it's the OU Process.

Comment: Well, I don't know what you are allowed to use. Solutions to non-degenerate and time-homohenuous SDEs always satisfy the Markov property, so does OU.